# Java erro: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: java

In my program the user inputs a boat name and an argument (boat, args). I am trying to write a conditional that prints different things in the console depending what the user inputs as arg. But I am getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at kristenalbrechtproject8.main.main(main.java:91)
C:\Users\Kristen Albrecht\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

I know it has something to do with my args array but I am new to java and unsure how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

```
public class main {

/**

* @param args

* the command line arguments

*/

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String filename = "Boats.txt";

    // PrintWriter out;

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    FileReader f = new FileReader(filename);

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(f);

    while(keyboard.hasNextLine()){

        list.add(keyboard.nextLine());

    }

    System.out.println("File Contents: " + list);

    System.out.println("Enter boat name (name) or quit: ");

    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (keyboard.hasNextLine()) {

        String input = keyboard.nextLine();

    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {

        break;

    }

    String[] tokens = input.split(",");

    if (tokens.length != 2) {

        System.out.println("Invalid format, try again");

        continue;

    }

    String name = tokens[0].trim();

    System.out.printf("%-10s \r\n", name, args);

    if(list.contains(name)){

        System.out.println(name + " found in file");

        if(args[1].equals("power on"))
        {
            System.out.println(name + " power up the boat");
        }
        else if(args[1].equals("power off"))
        {
            System.out.println(name + " turn off the boat");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(name + " command does not exist");
        }

     }else{

        System.out.println(name + " not found in file");

     }

    System.out.println("Enter boat name (name) or quit: ");

    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    }

    keyboard.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you are passing just one parameter or even no parameters in the console but you are trying to get parameter at position 1 therefore it results in ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

You need to check how many parameters you have:

```
if (args.length >= 2) {
    if (args[1].equals("power on")) {
        ... do what you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using args[1] in the code. you will have to pass in atleast two args to your program and also remember to put them in quotes as you expect to have space in them, like "power on"

Answer (score 0):

Every array-index starts with 0. So your first argument lies in args[0]. Also keep in mind that you have to concat "power on" with the quotationmarks, otherwise it will be read as two arguments. But as your error suggests I think you are already doing that.